# Returning value from HKCR using Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a function in Powershell that returns the path from where a COM dll is registered; within the function correct path is returned but when this function is invoked, there is an extra string "HKCR" prefixed to the output

```
function com_registeredpath()
{  
    param([string]$guid)

    New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

    $key = Get-Item "HKCR:\CLSID\$guid\InprocServer32"
    $values = Get-ItemProperty $key.PSPath

    [string] $defaultValue = [string] $values."(default)"
    write-host ">>>: $defaultValue" # returns a value like: c:\somefolder\somefile.dll

    remove-psdrive -name HKCR
    return $defaultValue
}

write-host "~~~" (com_registeredpath "{00F97463-DF44-11D1-BED5-00600831F894}") #   returns a value like: HKCR c:\somefolder\somefile.dll
```

Can some one explain this strange behaviour? I would expect both return values to be same.

Answer (score 11):

I don't get a path prefixed with the reg hive.
First, you need to suppress the result of the new psdrive, you don't want the function to return anything but the dll path (I assigned it to null).
Lastly, you can get the value without crating a psdrive, just use the provider path for HKCR

```sh
function Get-ComRegisteredPath
{
    param( [string]$Guid )

    try
    {
        $reg = Get-ItemProperty "Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\$Guid\InprocServer32" -ErrorAction Stop
        $reg.'(default)'
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Error $_ 
    }   
}

PS> Get-ComRegisteredPath -Guid '{00F97463-DF44-11D1-BED5-00600831F894}'
```

Answer (score 4):

I just cleaned it up a bit and this version gives me the right string.

```sh
function com_registeredpath()
{  
    param([string]$guid)
    New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT | Out-Null
    $key = Get-Item "HKCR:\CLSID\$guid\InprocServer32"
    $values = Get-ItemProperty $key.PSPath

    return $values.'(default)'
}

com_registeredpath "{0000002F-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
```